# Importing sensitive data from SQL server to a flat file

Tags: ssis, etl, ssis-2012, ssis-2008, derived-column

I am new to SSIS and I  want to import data from the SQL database to a flat-file.
I have a column name named `SecurityNumber` which contains sensitive data, so using a derived column I want to use a symbol * to hide some numbers.
For example, if the column has a value 1983121802 and
if substring 3 plus substring 4 (in this case 8+3) is less than 13 display the column as  `**83******` or else display the whole value (`1983121802`) 
how can I do that? 
and the column `SecurityNumber` has a string data type, How can I change it to another data type so it's possible to make the comparison?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following expression:

```
((DT_I4)SUBSTRING([SecurityNumber],3,1) + (DT_I4)SUBSTRING([SecurityNumber],4,1)) > 13 ? [SecurityNumber] : "**" + SUBSTRING([SecurityNumber],3,2) + "******"
```